# jQuery: .is :last-child (or first-child) with specific class

Tags: jquery, css

I'm working on a catalog for bicycles which includes filtering and a lightbox for detailed information.

The bicycle overview consists of a large ul with li's in it, where each li represents one bicycle. Detailed information (which is used to filter) is set and read via data attributes. If a `li` has class `.show` it matches the filter criteria and is thus shown in the overview.

When navigating the lightbox (prev/next arrows) the user should only see the bicycles that match the criteria (has `.show`), which is what I've got working.

The last step (which I'm asking this question for) is: in the lightbox I want the 'previous' arrow to disappear when the first bicycle is active and the 'next' arrow should disappear when the last bicycle is active.

I tried this:

```
if ( info.is(":last-child") ) { 
    lightbox.find(".lightbox-nav-next").hide();
} else { 
    lightbox.find(".lightbox-nav-next").show();
};
```

Where `info` is the `li` that is being shown in the lightbox at that moment.

I'm wondering why `info.is(":last-child")` is not working... I think it is because it selects the last child without considering if it has class `.show`.

What is the best way to solve this?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
The page I'm talking about is online at: http://dev.onefinitystudios.com/rvs/verkoop.html. The file where the javascript is located is catalogus.js.

Comment: It would be nice to see the code that you're working with. An example from jsFiddle.net would also go a long way.

Comment: My bad, I added an url to the online version!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [:last](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) selector.

What you need to check is whether `info` is same as the last item with class `show`, it can be achieved with `$('.show:last').is(info)`.

```
if ( $('.show:last').is(info) ) { 
    lightbox.find(".lightbox-nav-next").hide();
} else { 
    lightbox.find(".lightbox-nav-next").show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lightbox.find(".lightbox-nav-next").toggle(function () {
  return ! info.is(".show:last");
});
```

and

```
lightbox.find(".lightbox-nav-prev").toggle(function () {
  return ! info.is(".show:first");
});
```

Comment: @Cas I mainly left it because the use of `.toggle()` instead of an "if (x) then .show() else .hide()" construct.

Comment: @Cas Of course `.is()` accepts a selector, so this becomes even more idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use jquery .last()

jquery .last() selects the last child anyway

So your code would be something like:

```
if ( info.last() ) { 
    lightbox.find(".lightbox-nav-next").hide();
} else { 
    lightbox.find(".lightbox-nav-next").show();
};
```

http://api.jquery.com/last/

Comment: I know, but using `.last()` I can't specify to only search for elements with a sepcific class (`.show`) either... So it is the same, right?

Comment: Both of the way that I said and the way that you said in your code bot look for the last child, neither of them check to see if the last li contains a class .show.

You will need to run another check in the if statement to see if the last li contains the class show

Comment: You may need to show more of your code and workings. As i am not sure how everything is working

Comment: Yes, that's why I asked the question. I needed a way to make sure it looked for the last child that has the class `.show`

Answer (score 0):

Try instead with `:last` (yes, its not from CSS, but a jQuery addition)

i.e.

```
if ( info.is(":last") ) { 
   ...
```

**[Docs](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)**